# What is causing my mesh to look lumpy in solid display

Tags: mesh, faces, normals

There is no duplicate geometry, no geometry behind the geometry, the normals and face orientation appear to be correct, shade smooth has no effect.

[image]

Comment: may you share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @a-python-script I figured it out. The normals looked right and I did a recalculate outside, which did nothing. But then I tried set from faces and that fixed it.

Comment: That’s a pretty common problem, where custom normals get screwed up and caused little artifacts like this. Please post your solution as an answer, it will probably be useful to someone eventually.